# Byte array to pdf through javascript

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, ajax, pdf

I have a webservice which gives me response in "BYTE ARRAY" and now i want to use that byte array to convert it into pdf file and download it..

for now am using java code as -

```
String genericResponseS="";
            OrderRequest orderRequest=null;
            String orderId=request.getParameter("orderId");
            FileOutputStream fileOuputStream=null;
            try {
                //$('#productName').val()
                orderRequest=new OrderRequest();
                orderRequest.setOrderId(Long.valueOf(orderId));
                orderRequest.setUserId(userBean.getUserID());
                //priceBookRequest.setCurrencyId(Long.parseLong(currencyId));
                byte[] arrayB=MobileServiceOrder.generateOrderPDF(orderRequest, request) ;
                /*response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "abc.pdf");
                    fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream("D:\\ORDER2.pdf"); 
                    fileOuputStream.write(arrayB);*/
                response.getOutputStream().write(arrayB);


and JAVASCRIPT CODE --
function generatePDF(orderId){

        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            url:"newOrder.do?parameter=generateOrderPDF&orderId="+orderId,
            data: $('#orderParamForm').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            documenttype: "application\pdf",
            async:false,
            success: function (data) {
            // window.open(data);
            saveByteArray(data);
            }
        });

    }

    function saveByteArray(byte) {
    debugger;
    var blob = new Blob([byte], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var fileName = "abc" + ".pdf";
    link.download = fileName;
    link.click();
};
```

//HELP WILL BE APPRECIATED